# R- Linear mixed model - significance of treatment within the fixed effect

Tags: r, mixed-model, least-squares

My questions: Is the 'least square means' good to look at the within fixed effect significance? - because I tried and get a very high degree of freedom.

In more details:

I am looking at the effect Temperature (27 vs 31 degree) and Flooding time (0, 2 and 6h) on CO2 emission of soil. I also have a random intercept (time).

My mixed model looks like that:
Model: CO2 ~ Temperature*Inundation + (1|Date)

My data like that: [image]

I would like to know my 'within fixed effect' effect :
For example see if the soil flooded for 0h at 27°C is different that the soil flooded for 0h at 31°C.

I tried to use the least square means to do that in R:

```
lsmeans(Model1_Full, pairwise ~  Temperature| Inundation)
```

The results seems okay- but the degree of Freedom seems uncorrect (290!!! - I have my total number of measurement equal to 300). So, I think something is wrong, but I don't know what.. Any idea? or any better method? - I need the level of significance.

part of my R result:

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Both temp and flooding are within-date factors, so the date effects cancel out when comparing them. I think this is probably in order. If you look at the EMMs themselves, the df will be lower because the day-to-day variations contribute to the uncertainty in estimating them.

Comment: BTW I always hate seeing people go straight to the comparisons and seeming not to look at the estimated means. Those should be interesting things to look at and to plot.

Comment: Thanks rvl for your answer! I Unfortunately, I did my best but did not understand your answer- I am still a novice in stat ;) . So,  If the date effect cancel out, the degree of freedom, should be lower. We would have temperature (2) x Inundation (3) -1 = 5 degrees of freedom (df). Also, I am unsure what do you mean by EMMs. Also, I did look a the estimated means, and plotted my data, but LS mean seems right, I just don't understand this very high degree of freedom.

Comment: The df reported are for error, not for the effects being estimated. Read `vignette(“basics”)` for more info

Comment: PS maybe you’re expecting to see an ANIVA table.  Try `car::Anova(Model1_Full)`. (You May need to do `install.packages(“car”)` first)

Comment: Thanks. The vignette for lsmeans migrate to the package emmeans.

Comment: So,in the result table, you get a 'fractional degree of freedom'. When you report your result, do you report this 'fractional degree of freedom or the one you get with car::Anova(Model1_Full). I am a bit lost. :(

Comment: The df in the result table are not just there as a decoration. Report them along with the means and SEs they accompany. Is there a stat department near you? There’s a lot more to this than running programs, and it sounds like you could use some consulting help.